# Is there a way in Linux to preserve folder size for safety

Tags: memory, home, size, out-of-memory

I want to install a data manipulation solution. The solution is deployed in a folder in home directory. Free space in disk is uncontrollable and can shrink at any moment (other users data).

How can I at first preserve say 100 giga bytes for only one folder.

Is it possible? if yes, then How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to create a separate partition on the disk for this special applicaiton's data storage. You can set the partition size to what ever you want and then mount the partition under your home directory.

Then as long as no one else has access to the partition (i.e. write permissions) then you should effectively have that space set aside on disk for your particular usage.